# Running multiple Google App Engines in a single project or across multiple projects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am looking for some recommendations in regards to using Google Cloud.

A cloud SQL service from Google is relatively expensive considering the size of my projects.

Would it make more sense to have ONE cloud SQL service under a single project and have all my Django apps run on different Google App Engines as separate 'services' also under the same project and have them all access the same SQL server (just different databases)?

Or maybe have a project which holds the SQL service and other projects for all the Django apps and have those apps access the same Cloud SQL service running on a different project?

Or maybe there is a 3rd solution?

Comment: The first approach is natural and simple. Connecting to Cloud SQL through vpc connectors minimizes traffic costs. The second approach will require additional management of projects, establishing shared VPC and so on. If you plan to grow your django apps then separate project for each app might be a good idea, otherwise it is just excessive manual work I think.

Comment: Something to consider...  The NoSQL alternatives are very low cost with generous free tier.